# Java-client-api to trigger jenkins job from java.. works on local jenkins but fails on remote server

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I m executing a java programme to run a jenkins job ( name “terraform-example” ) which runs on the same machine it works fine.
But when I point to a remote Jenkins server it throws exception though port is open and web URL can be accessed from remote
Here is the code

```
 import java.net.URI;
 import com.offbytwo.jenkins.JenkinsServer;
 import com.offbytwo.jenkins.model.BuildWithDetails;

 public class Main {
      public static void main(String args) {

      try
       { JenkinsServer jenkinsServer = new 
                                          JenkinsServer(new 
          
         URI(“http://localhost:8080/"),“admin”,"apitoken”); 
        // JenkinsServer jenkinsServer = new JenkinsServer(   
               URI.create(“http://192.168.1.207:8080/")
              ,“admin”,"apitoken”); 

           JenkinsTriggerHelper triggerHelper = new 
           JenkinsTriggerHelper(jenkinsServer); 
            BuildWithDetails 
                          details =      triggerHelper.triggerJobAndWaitUntilFinished(“terraform-example”); 
      if (details!=null) 
           System.out.println("LOGS " + 
           details.getConsoleOutputText()); 
      else 
           System.out.println("details not found " ); }
      catch (Exception e)

             { 
               e.printStackTrace(); 
             }
          }
          }
```

exception    org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
192.168.1.207:8080 [/192.168.1.207] failed: Connection
timed out: connect

Comment: Looks like a network error/issue?

Comment: Can you ping `192.168.1.207` and telnet `192.168.1.207:8080` from where you are executing the Java code?

Comment: yes i tried both. and both works... ping and telnet

Comment: To have productive Jenkins on HTTP/8080 is suspicious. Maybe try using HTTPS on the correct port. How exactly do you connect to Jenkins frontend in the web browser, it should be the same for the API?